# Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED when doing react-native run-android

Tags: android, react-native

I'm getting the following error while building my app using react-native run-android:

> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
195 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 193 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
> /Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/863e0c3c6716935cd3657ad638fd992d/material-1.1.0/res/values/values.xml:528:5-593:11: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/contextPopupMenuStyle' not found.

```
 /Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/863e0c3c6716935cd3657ad638fd992d/material-1.1.0/res/values/values.xml:642:5-699:11: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/contextPopupMenuStyle' not found.
     
 /Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/863e0c3c6716935cd3657ad638fd992d/material-1.1.0/res/values/values.xml:748:5-812:11: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/contextPopupMenuStyle' not found.
     
 /Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/863e0c3c6716935cd3657ad638fd992d/material-1.1.0/res/values/values.xml:909:5-966:11: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/contextPopupMenuStyle' not found.
     
 /Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/863e0c3c6716935cd3657ad638fd992d/material-1.1.0/res/values/values.xml:1023:5-1034:11: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/dialogCornerRadius' not found.
     
 /Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/1cb9b9ea592aa2ea85233be252327dcf/appcompat-1.1.0/res/values-v26/values-v26.xml:5:5-8:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
     
 /Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/1cb9b9ea592aa2ea85233be252327dcf/appcompat-1.1.0/res/values-v26/values-v26.xml:9:5-12:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
     
 /Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/1cb9b9ea592aa2ea85233be252327dcf/appcompat-1.1.0/res/values-v26/values-v26.xml:13:5-16:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/keyboardNavigationCluster' not found.
     
 /Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/1cb9b9ea592aa2ea85233be252327dcf/appcompat-1.1.0/res/values-v28/values-v28.xml:5:5-8:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
     
 /Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/1cb9b9ea592aa2ea85233be252327dcf/appcompat-1.1.0/res/values-v28/values-v28.xml:9:5-12:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
     
 /Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/1cb9b9ea592aa2ea85233be252327dcf/appcompat-1.1.0/res/values-v23/values-v23.xml:38:5-41:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/hyphenationFrequency' not found.
     
 /Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/1cb9b9ea592aa2ea85233be252327dcf/appcompat-1.1.0/res/values-v23/values-v23.xml:38:5-41:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/breakStrategy' not found.
     
 /Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/1cb9b9ea592aa2ea85233be252327dcf/appcompat-1.1.0/res/values-v23/values-v23.xml:45:5-48:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/hyphenationFrequency' not found.
     
 /Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/1cb9b9ea592aa2ea85233be252327dcf/appcompat-1.1.0/res/values-v23/values-v23.xml:45:5-48:13: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/breakStrategy' not found.
     
 /Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/7ce8a2eb9e81825ec9bcc373c597a746/cardview-1.0.0/res/values-v23/values-v23.xml:3:5-5:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorBackgroundFloating not found.
     
 /Users/prikshetsharma/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/863e0c3c6716935cd3657ad638fd992d/material-1.1.0/res/values/values.xml:1709:5-1716:11: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/keyboardNavigationCluster' not found.
```

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

How to fix this error?

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had to bump my compileSdkVersion in a module (LVL licensing). Very annoying since the error was manifesting under a completely different module.